# Appending reference to url to BundleContext.installBundle

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

I have observed there are 2 ways to pass url to BundleContext.installBundle function as below:

```
String installURL1 = "file:///abc/def.jar
```

Or

```
String installURL2 = "reference:file:abc/def.jar";
```

What is the difference in these 2 and which one is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

The **file** will copy the JAR file inside the working container and will use from them, while with **reference** the container will load from the direct location - it will use as a link. I'm not sure the reference can be a JAR file, as I know it is used to load directory content. (for example in development the target folder of compilation) and its handled as a bundle. Not all OSGi container supports reference, but felix and equinox are.